# Change the default model binder in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way I can set the default ModelBinder to one of my own?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyOwnModelBinder();
```

Comment: Where does this go? In `Global.asax.cs` ? Or somewhere else?

Comment: i believe so... in MvcApplication.Application_Start()

Answer (score -1):

In the *Global.asax.cs*:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //...
            ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyModelBinder();
        }

    }
```