# In ASP.NET MVC can url parameter name be different than model's property name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.Net MVC 2 - Bind a model's property to a different named value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value)

Given following url:

```
~/mycontroller/myaction/?REG_NAME=123
```

following action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(ActionRequest model)
```

and model:

```
public class ActionRequest
{
    [ThisIsTheAttributeNameImLookingFor("REG_NAME")]
    public string RegisteredTo { get; set;}
}
```

How can I map model's property (RegisteredTo) to url parameter (REG_NAME) with **different name**?

Inheriting CustomModelBinderAttribute is not the option, as it can not be applied to properties.

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate. Although the second response is better, than the one marked as answer. Unless someone knows an easier way I vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

No such attribute exists. You either use a custom model binder, or a custom TypeDescriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can it like this:

```
public class ActionRequest
{
    private string REG_NAME { get; set;}

    public string RegisteredTo { get { return REG_NAME; } set { this.REG_NAME = value; } ;}
}
```