# How to bind view model property with different name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-5

**Is there a way to make a reflection for a view model property as an element with different name and id values on the html side.**

That is the main question of what I want to achieve. So the basic introduction for the question is like:

1- I have a view model (as an example) which created for a filter operation in view side.

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string FilterParameter { get; set; }
}
```

2- I have a controller action which is created for GETting form values(here it is filter)

```
public ActionResult Index(FilterViewModel filter)
{
return View();
}
```

3- I have a view that a user can filter on some data and sends parameters via querystring over form submit.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Demo", FormMethod.Get))
{    
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FilterParameter)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FilterParameter)
    <input type="submit" value="Do Filter" />
}
```

4- And what I want to see in rendered view output is

```
<form action="/Demo" method="get">
    <label for="fp">FilterParameter</label>
    <input id="fp" name="fp" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Do Filter" />
</form>
```

5- And as a solution I want to modify my view model like this:

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    [BindParameter("fp")]
    [BindParameter("filter")] // this one extra alias
    [BindParameter("param")] //this one extra alias
    public string FilterParameter { get; set; }
}
```

So the basic question is about BindAttribute but the usage of complex type properties. But also if there is a built in way of doing this is much better. 
Built-in pros:

1- Usage with TextBoxFor, EditorFor, LabelFor and other strongly typed view model helpers can understand and communicate better with each other.

2- Url routing support

3- No framework by desing problems :

> In general, we recommend folks don’t write custom model binders
>   because they’re difficult to get right and they’re rarely needed. The
>   issue I’m discussing in this post might be one of those cases where
>   it’s warranted.

[Link of quote](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/)

And also after some research I found these useful works:

[Binding model property with different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value)

[One step upgrade of first link](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/bind-a-model-property-to-a-different-named-query-string-field/)

[Here some informative guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507699/how-to-bind-url-parameters-to-model-properties-with-different-names)

Result: But none of them give me my problems exact solution. I am looking for a strongly typed solution for this problem. Of course if you know any other way to go, please share.

---

**Update**

The underlying reasons why I want to do this are basically:

1- Everytime I want to change the html control name then I have to change PropertyName at compile time. (There is a difference Changing a property name between changing a string in code)

2- I want to hide (camouflage) real property names from end users. Most of times View Model property names same as mapped Entity Objects property names. (For developer readability reasons)

3- I don't want to remove the readability for developer. Think about lots of properties with like 2-3 character long and with mo meanings.

4- There are lots of view models written. So changing their names are going to take more time than this solution.

5- This is going to be better solution (in my POV) than others which are described in other questions until now.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve that is to use `Fp` as property name in your view model instead of `FilterParameter`. After all, that's what view models are intended for: express the view requirements. There's no way to modify the standard helpers. If you write custom attributes and decorate your view model properties, you will have to write custom model binder that understands them and also you will have to write custom HTML helpers.

Comment: For some reason it is too much work to change property name :) Yes viewmodel are for this reason but it is not a drawback for my problem, is it?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case if you are using view models because view models are designed exactly for that purpose. And believe me, if changing the view name property is too much work, achieving what you are asking for here would be like rewriting the entire ASP.NET MVC framework :-) So it's up to you to decide which way you prefer to go. Yeah, I know, it's too much of work because you are not using view models but instead you simply passed this domain business model to your view. BAD, BAD, BAD. Next time you will know.

Comment: I checked mvc input extension codes I know I can't change them but you are saying also I can't do anything for this to make work.

Comment: No, I am not saying that. What I am saying is that in order to do this you will have to write your own custom extension helpers to replace the default ones. So basically you will be reinventing the wheels and rewriting the entire framework.

Comment: No I am using viewmodels for my view object. I just want something like JsonProperty[PropertyName="foo"] like in the Newtonsoft.JSON.

Comment: Well, you might want that, but it's not easy to achieve it. Also if you are using view models, simply rename your view model property to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @YusufUzun Where is the BindParameter attribute documented?  I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: this bites me at least once a year, then I get sad that everything in my project isn't just JSON

Comment: If it would be ok to set the name to bind in the view instead of ViewModel you could set the htmlFieldName parameter of the EditorFor overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_EditorExtensions_EditorFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_String_System_String_

Answer (score 11):

Actually, there is a way to do it.

In ASP.NET binding metadata gathered by [`TypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx), not by reflection directly. To be more precious, [`AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.associatedmetadatatypetypedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) is used, which, in turn, simply calls `TypeDescriptor.GetProvider` with our model type as parameter:

```
public AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(Type type)
  : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(type))
{
}
```

So, everything we need is to set our custom [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) for our model.

Let's implement our custom provider. First of all, let's define attribute for custom property name:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CustomBindingNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CustomBindingNameAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }
}
```

If you already have attribute with desired name, you can reuse it. Attribute defined above is just an example. I prefer to use [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonpropertyattribute.htm) because in most cases I work with json and Newtonsoft's library and want to define custom name only once.

The next step is to define custom type descriptor. We will not implement whole type descriptor logic and use default implementation. Only property accessing will be overridden:

```
public class MyTypeDescription : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public MyTypeDescription(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent)
        : base(parent)
    {
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return Wrap(base.GetProperties());
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return Wrap(base.GetProperties(attributes));
    }

    private static PropertyDescriptorCollection Wrap(PropertyDescriptorCollection src)
    {
        var wrapped = src.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                         .Select(pd => (PropertyDescriptor)new MyPropertyDescriptor(pd))
                         .ToArray();

        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(wrapped);
    }
}
```

Also custom property descriptor need to be implemented. Again, everything except property name will be handled by default descriptor. Note, `NameHashCode` for some reason is a separate property. As name changed, so it's hash code need to be changed too:

```
public class MyPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private readonly PropertyDescriptor _descr;
    private readonly string _name;

    public MyPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor descr)
        : base(descr)
    {
        this._descr = descr;

        var customBindingName = this._descr.Attributes[typeof(CustomBindingNameAttribute)] as CustomBindingNameAttribute;
        this._name = customBindingName != null ? customBindingName.PropertyName : this._descr.Name;
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
    }

    protected override int NameHashCode
    {
        get { return this.Name.GetHashCode(); }
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return this._descr.CanResetValue(component);
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return this._descr.GetValue(component);
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        this._descr.ResetValue(component);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        this._descr.SetValue(component, value);
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return this._descr.ShouldSerializeValue(component);
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return this._descr.ComponentType; }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return this._descr.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return this._descr.PropertyType; }
    }
}
```

Finally, we need our custom [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and way to bind it to our model type. By default, [`TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionproviderattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is designed to perform that binding. But in this case we will not able to get default provider that we want to use internally. In most cases, default provider will be `ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider`. But this is not guaranteed and this provider is inaccessible due to it's protection level - it's `internal`. But we do still want to fallback to default provider.

`TypeDescriptor` also allow to explicitly add provider for our type via [`AddProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.addprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) method. That what we will use. But firstly, let's define our custom provider itself:

```
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private readonly TypeDescriptionProvider _defaultProvider;

    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider defaultProvider)
    {
        this._defaultProvider = defaultProvider;
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return new MyTypeDescription(this._defaultProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance));
    }
}
```

The last step is to bind our provider to our model types. We can implement it in any way we want. For example, let's define some simple class, such as:

```
public static class TypeDescriptorsConfig
{
    public static void InitializeCustomTypeDescriptorProvider()
    {
        // Assume, this code and all models are in one assembly
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                            .Where(t => t.GetProperties().Any(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CustomBindingNameAttribute))));

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var defaultProvider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(type);
            TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new MyTypeDescriptionProvider(defaultProvider), type);
        }
    }
}
```

And either invoke that code via web activation:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TypeDescriptorsConfig), "InitializeCustomTypeDescriptorProvider")]
```

Or simply call it in `Application_Start` method:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        TypeDescriptorsConfig.InitializeCustomTypeDescriptorProvider();

        // rest of init code ...
    }
}
```

But this is not the end of the story. :(

Consider following model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [CustomBindingName("actual_name")]
    [DisplayName("Yay!")]
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If we try to write in `.cshtml` view something like:

```
@model Some.Namespace.TestModel
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.TestProperty) @* fail *@
```

We will get `ArgumentException`:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The property Some.Namespace.TestModel.TestProperty could not be found.

That because all helpers soon or later invoke [`ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393(v=vs.118).aspx) method. And this method take expression we provided (`x => x.TestProperty`) and takes member name directly from member info and have no clue about any of our attributes, metadata *(who cares, huh?)*:

```
internal static ModelMetadata FromLambdaExpression<TParameter, TValue>(/* ... */)
{
    // ...

        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
            propertyName = memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo ? memberExpression.Member.Name : (string) null;
            //                                  I want to cry here - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    // ...
}
```

For `x => x.TestProperty` (where `x` is `TestModel`) this method will return `TestProperty`, not `actual_name`, but model metadata contains `actual_name` property, have no `TestProperty`. That is why `the property could not be found` error thrown.

This is a *design failure*.

However despite this little inconvenience there are several workarounds, such as:

1. The easiest way is to access our members by theirs redefined names:

   ```
   @model Some.Namespace.TestModel
   @Html.DisplayName("actual_name") @* this will render "Yay!" *@
   ```

   This is not good. No intellisense at all and as our model change we will have no any compilation errors. On any change anything can be broken and there is no easy way to detect that.
2. Another way is a bit more complex - we can create our own version of that helpers and forbid anybody from calling default helpers or  `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression` for model classes with renamed properties.
3. Finally, combination of previous two would be preferred: write own analogue to get property name with redefinition support, then pass that into default helper. Something like this:

   ```
   @model Some.Namespace.TestModel
   @Html.DisplayName(Html.For(x => x.TestProperty))
   ```

   Compilation-time and intellisense support and no need to spend a lot of time for complete set of helpers. Profit!

Also everything described above work like a charm for model binding. During model binding process default binder also use metadata, gathered by `TypeDescriptor`.

But I guess binding json data is the best use case. You know, lots of web software and standards use `lowercase_separated_by_underscores` naming convention. Unfortunately this is not usual convention for C#. Having classes with members named in different convention looks ugly and can end up in troubles. Especially when you have tools that whining every time about naming violation.

ASP.NET MVC default model binder does not bind json to model the same way as it happens when you call newtonsoft's `JsonConverter.DeserializeObject` method. Instead, json parsed into dictionary. For example:

```
{
    complex: {
        text: "blabla",
        value: 12.34
    },
    num: 1
}
```

will be translated into following dictionary:

```
{ "complex.text", "blabla" }
{ "complex.value", "12.34" }
{ "num", "1" }
```

And later these values along with others values from query string, route data and so on, collected by different implementations of [`IValueProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ivalueprovider(v=vs.118).aspx), will be used by default binder to bind a model with help of metadata, gathered by `TypeDescriptor`.

So we came full circle from creating model, rendering, binding it back and use it.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is NO and long answer still NO. There is no built-in helper, attribute, model binder, whatever is it (Nothing out of box).

But what I did in before answer (I deleted it) was an awful solution that I realized yesterday. I am going to put it in github for who still wants to see (maybe it solves somebody problem) (I don't suggest it also!)

Now I searched it for again and I couldn't find anything helpful. If you are using something like AutoMapper or ValueInjecter like tool for mapping your ViewModel objects to Business objects and if you want to obfuscate that View Model parameters also, probably you are in some trouble. Of course you can do it but strongly typed html helpers are not going to help you alot. I even not talking about the if other developers taking branch and working over common view models.

Luckily my project (4 people working on it, and its commercial use for) not that big for now, so I decided to change View Model property names! (It is still lot work to do. Hundreds of view models to obfuscate their properties!!!) Thank you Asp.Net MVC !

There some ways in the links which I gave in question. But also if you still want to use the BindAlias attribute, I can only suggest you to use the following extension methods. At least you dont have to write same alias string which you write in BindAlias attribute.

Here it is:

```
public static string AliasNameFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = ExpressionHelpers.GetMemberExpression(expression);
    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression");
    var aliasAttr = memberExpression.Member.GetAttribute<BindAliasAttribute>();
    if (aliasAttr != null)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(aliasAttr.Alias).ToHtmlString();
    }
    return htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToHtmlString();
}

public static string AliasIdFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = ExpressionHelpers.GetMemberExpression(expression);
    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression");
    var aliasAttr = memberExpression.Member.GetAttribute<BindAliasAttribute>();
    if (aliasAttr != null)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(aliasAttr.Alias)).ToHtmlString();
    }
    return htmlHelper.IdFor(expression).ToHtmlString();
}



public static T GetAttribute<T>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    where T : Attribute
{
    var attributes = provider.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true);
    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0] as T : null;
}

public static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression;
    if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
    {
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
        memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
    }
    else
    {
        memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    }
    return memberExpression;
}
```

When you want to use it:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(AliasModelBinder))]
public class FilterViewModel
{
    [BindAlias("someText")]
    public string FilterParameter { get; set; }
}
```

In html:

```
@* at least you dont write "someText" here again *@
@Html.Editor(Html.AliasNameFor(model => model.FilterParameter))
@Html.ValidationMessage(Html.AliasNameFor(model => model.FilterParameter))
```

So I am leaving this answer here like this. This is even not an answer (and there is no answer for MVC 5) but who searching in google for same problem might find useful this experience.

And here is the github repo: https://github.com/yusufuzun/so-view-model-bind-20869735

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you still have the original source? It looks like your repo no longer exists. I realize you've published some source above, but being new to MVC I'd like to see it all in place and working correctly. IOW a fully working sample. I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63802863), and it looks like I might be able to do so with this. Would you agree?

Comment: Repo link does not work. I found [this](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/bind-a-model-property-to-a-different-named-query-string-field/) _(not mine)_ implementation of AliasModelBinder.