# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding with Dashes in Form Element Names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model-binding

I have been scouring the internet trying to find a way to accomodate dashes from my form elements into the default model binding behavior of ASP.NET's Controllers in MVC 2, 3, or even 4.

As a front-end developer, I prefer dashes in my CSS over camelCase or underscores.  In my markup, what I want to be able to do to is something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="first-name" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="last-name" class="required" />
```

In the controller, I would be passing in a C# object that would look like this:

```
public class Person
{
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      //etc...
}
```

Is there some way to extend the `Controller` class to accommodate this through some regex or other behavior?  I hate the fact that I have to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="person.firstname" class="required" />
```

or even this:

```
<input type="text" name="isPersonAttending" class="required" />
```

Thoughts?

Comment: consider my answer to my own question about shortening model property names, where I show how to alias them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value#answer-4316327

Answer (score 7):

You could always create your own model binder.

Here's an example that implements a binder that supports adding Aliases to model properties:

http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/bind-a-model-property-to-a-different-named-query-string-field/

And with it do something like:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(AliasModelBinder))]
public class Person
{
      [BindAlias("first-name")]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      [BindAlias("last-name")]
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      //etc...
}
```

**EDIT:**
This implementation, as the blogger says, is based on Andras' answer on the following SO question:
[Asp.Net MVC 2 - Bind a model's property to a different named value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value#answer-4316327)

Comment: please note that, as the blog author says, that, and therefore this, is a copy of my own answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value#answer-4316327

Comment: This is logical and makes great sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Andras, you are totally correct, I hadn't seen the reference to your answer. Sorry about that. BTW, great implementation.

Comment: Hi @pabloromeo don't worry, it's cool, and thanks :-) just glad to see it's  helping others!

Comment: No prob. I just added the reference to your answer too ;)

Answer (score 4):

For readers looking for an ASP.NET Core solution, try one of the `[From...]` attributes. For example:

```
public class Person
{
    [FromForm(Name = "first-name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [FromForm(Name = "last-name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //etc...
}
```

The `[From...]` attributes are briefly described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources.

Answer (score 3):

By creating a custom form value provider you could solve this problem easily. The other advantage is you can avoid polluting all the model properties by decorating custom attributes.

**Custom Form Value Provider**

```
public class DashFormValueProvider : NameValueCollectionValueProvider
{
    public DashFormValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    : base(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form, 
    controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated().Form, 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    {
    }

    public override bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return base.ContainsPrefix(GetModifiedPrefix(prefix));
    }

    public override ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        return base.GetValue(GetModifiedPrefix(key));
    }

    public override ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key, bool skipValidation)
    {
        return base.GetValue(GetModifiedPrefix(key), skipValidation);
    }

    // this will convert the key "FirstName" to "first-name".
    private string GetModifiedPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(prefix, "([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))", "$1-").ToLower();
    }
}
```

**Value Provider Factory**

```
public class DashFormValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }

        return new DashFormValueProvider(controllerContext);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new DashFormValueProviderFactory());
```

Comment: Nice! I would agree with you - if you were using dashes for most of your form element names, using attributes would be a bit much.  Thanks for the share!