# ASP.NET MVC and Web API model binding - how do I bind to properties with names disallowed by the language?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

An example of basic model binding to an object in ASP.NET MVC or the ASP.NET Web API might look like this (using C# as example):

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string value1 { get; set; } 
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}

public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyModel model) { ... }
}
```

As long as the POST body looks like `value1=somevalue&value2=someothervalue` things map just fine.

But how do I handle a scenario where the post body contains parameter names that are disallowed as class property names, such as `body-text=bla&...`?

Comment: Why do you have `body-text` in post body anyway?

Comment: @artm Because that's what the service that is sending me a webhook is naming one of their parameters.  It's an email service so they are referring the body of an email.  It's just a name, it could be "foo-bar".  The "body" in "body-text" has nothing to do with a post body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding with Dashes in Form Element Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173398/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-with-dashes-in-form-element-names)

Comment: Also, this might be worth looking at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461365/using-a-dash-in-asp-mvc-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461365/using-a-dash-in-asp-mvc-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to utilize data serialization attributes to help you with this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "body-text")]
    public string value1 { get; set; } 
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Whichever property I stick the attribute on comes up as null.  I used your model example and sent the following post body `body-text=mybodytext&value2=bla`.  value1 was null and value2 was "bla".

Answer (score 1):

You can force Asp.Net to use the Newtonsoft.JSON deserializer by passing a JObject to your action, although it is a bit annoying to have to do it like this.

Then you can work with it as a JObject or call `.ToObject<T>();` which will then honor the `JsonProperty` attribute.

```
// POST api/values
public IHttpActionResult Post(JObject content)
{
    var test = content.ToObject<MyModel>();
    // now you have your object with the properties filled according to JsonProperty attributes.
    return Ok();
}
```

MyModel example:

```
 public class MyModel
 {
     [JsonProperty(Name = "body-text")]
     public string value1 { get; set; } 

     public string value2 { get; set; }
 }
```