# How binding big array to small name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have class:

`EmployeeListViewModel` with property `List<Int32> EmployeeIDs`.

I need transfer with get request.

I do not want to see a request like `EmployeeIDs[]=1&EmployeeIDs[]=2` ...

I want to specify a tag which has a short name of this parameter

example:

```
empl[]=1&empl[]=2
```

Comment: There is a `Bind Attribute` on asp.net mvc. Maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate the controller action argument with the [`[Bind]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute and specify a prefix:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "empl[]")] int[] employeeIDs)
{
    ...
}
```

Now the following request will be correctly bound:

```
empl[]=1&empl[]=2
```

Comment: This way I know, and if it is in the class?

Comment: That's not supported by the default model binder. If you need to support such scenario you will have to write a custom model binder. But usually I wouldn't bother with that. I would simply match my view model property name with the expected query string name. It's much easier and one of the uses of a view model.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using Model Binding and want to customize the way binding happens. Unfortunately, on a `Model` class, I don't know of a way to use attributes to accomplish this, but you can accomplish what you want using a custom binder.

You'll need to implement the `IModelBinder` interface, and then use a `[ModelBinder]` attribute on your Controller's action method.

More details here: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx