# MVC4 Mailgun delivered webhook

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, webhooks, mailgun

I'm having an issue making use of the Mailgun delivered webhook, it can be found here: http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html#events-webhooks, look for "Delivered Event Webhook"

I am unable to reference Request.Params["Message-Id"] unless I modify the app's requestValidationMode to 2.0

I do get the potentially unsafe error when trying to reference this field without requestValidationMode = 2.0.  The contents of the field are: <20130203200110.12345.12345@mydomain.mailgun.org>.  I've also tried to declare a model to take advantage of auto model binding.  My model looks like this:

```
public class MailgunDeliveredEvent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="Message-Id")]
    public object MessageId { get; set; }

    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }        
}
```

When I attempt to reference the MessageId field it returns null.  I've tried to add

```
[Bind(Exclude="message-headers")]
```

As I'm not interested in that field.
In the Controller, I've set

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

I can't seem to get the Message-Id field back.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have got it working, in case anyone runs into the same issue...

I added a new model binder as referenced here:

[Asp.Net MVC 2 - Bind a model's property to a different named value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value)

I then changed my model like so:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(DefaultModelBinderEx))]
public class MailgunDeliveredEvent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [BindAlias("Message-Id")]
    public string MessageId { get; set; }

    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }        
}
```

And all seems to work, I didn't need to call

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

on the controller either.

Hope that helps someone.