# Shortening querystring names from view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, data-annotations

I am looking for a way in my view models to shorten property names in the querystring for a search form.  For example,  the verbose property name could be query but you see q in the querystring.

Currently, I am doing the following to achieve this.

```
public string Query { get; set; }
public string q
{
  get
  {
    return Query;
  }
  set
  {
    Query = value;
  }
}
```

I would think it might be easier if there was a data annotation to help with this.

```
[Querystring(Name="q")]
public string Query { get; set; }
```

Is there a better way to do this that I am not thinking of or is it possible to code my own data annotation like that?

Comment: i think it's possible to create a custom attributes like that (i haven't try it myself though :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own `ModelBinder`.

Have a look at:

1. [Bind a model property to a different named query string field](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/bind-a-model-property-to-a-different-named-query-string-field/)
2. [Asp.Net MVC 2 - Bind a model's property to a different named value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value)