# Map post parameters to a model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model I want to use for communication with an external web service. It's supposed to call a specific post action on my website.

```
public class ConfirmationModel{
    ...
    public string TransactionNumber {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult Confirmation(ConfirmationModel){
...
}
```

The problem is the parameters names they pass are not very human-readable. And I want to map them to my  more readable model.

```
't_numb' ====> 'TransactionNumber'
```

Can this be done automatically? With an attribute maybe? What's the best approach here?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value/4316327#4316327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model binder:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ModelBinder.Controllers;

public class ConfirmationModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = new ConfirmationModel();

        var transactionNumberParam = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("t_numb");

        if (transactionNumberParam != null)
            model.TransactionNumber = transactionNumberParam.AttemptedValue;

        return model;
    }
}
```

Initialise it in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ConfirmationModel), new ConfirmationModelBinder());
}
```

Then in your action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirmation(ConfirmationModel viewModel)
```

You should see the value of `t_numb` appear in `TransactionNumber` property of the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that model binder is better: here's an alternate idea though

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection values)
{
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
    recipe.Name = values["Name"];      

    // ...

    return View();
}
```

and a good read about both: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx