# Remove prefix from posted data in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, modelbinder

I have a view which looks like below. Each field has a prefix attached in the name property, but the model in my backend has property without the prefix.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="prefix" value="prefix"/>
        <input type="text" id="prefix.Name" name="prefix.Name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

My Action Method looks something like below :

```
public ActionResult Save([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]Employee employee)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

My Model looks like :

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Can someone help me how to achieve this through custom model binder, i want to strip prefix from each of the posted form items name.

Posted form data :

```
prefix:prefix
prefix.Name:Hello World!!
```

I tried below code as well but it's not working. Can someone explain whats wrong here.

```
public ActionResult Save([Bind(Prefix = "prefix")]Employee employee)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what you need: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Comment: I have already looked at it. This is an example of custom model binder. My requirement is similar to this but not exactly the same. My form data has prefix value, i want to strip that prefix value before model binding happens so that it can get binded to my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a binding prefix value, like this:

```
public ActionResult SetPassword([Bind(Prefix = "Form")] UserSetPasswordForm form)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Below code is not working, value of Name property is just prefix now :public ActionResult Save([Bind(Prefix = "prefix")]string Name)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BindAttribute` for his

```
public ActionResult Submit([Bind(Prefix = "L")] string[] longPropertyName) {

}
```

there is a similar question to yours here:
[Asp.Net MVC 2 - Bind a model's property to a different named value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value)

Answer (score 0):

There was some strange behavior, when i changed my prefix value it started working.

```
public ActionResult Save([Bind(Prefix = "**someothervalue**")]Employee employee)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Thanks everyone for your help.