# Binding to a name that is not a legal C# variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Google ReCaptcha element on a form.  ReCaptcha adds a parameter to the POSTed parameters named `g-recaptcha-response`, which the controller needs to retrieve. Since this parameter name is not a legal C# variable name, it seems that the only way to retrieve its value is via `Request.Params["g-recaptcha-response"]` (rather than via model binding to a property in the view model).

Now, my problem is that elsewhere in the POSTed parameters I have a couple of form fields that may contain HTML markup. I have annotated the associated properties in my view model with `[AllowHtml]`, which prevents the model binder from throwing an `HttpRequestValidationException` if the user enters HTML markup into the form. But `[AllowHtml]` apparently *only works in the model binder*. If the user has entered HTML markup into the form, then I get an `HttpRequestValidationException` when I reference `Request.Params` to fetch the ReCaptcha response.

As near as I can tell, the only way I can fetch the ReCaptcha response while still allowing HTML markup in selected POST parameters is to use go through the pain of writing a custom model binder (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316327/1637105) to allow me to bind a property in my view model to an alias (in my case, a property name that is not a valid C# variable name).

**The point of this question is just to confirm that I really do need to go to the pain of implementing a custom model binder.**

Any suggestions or alternate solutions are more than welcome!

EDIT:

It occurs to me that another solution would be to figure out a way to fetch the value from the POSTed parameters without triggering (or while handling) the HttpRequestValidationException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Unvalidated` property of `Request` to access values without triggering Request Validation. for example

```
var captcha = Request.Unvalidated.Form["g-recaptcha-response"];
```