# How to handle .NET Core Model Binding when form control has dash (-) in property name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-binding

Suppose I have the following input control in a form

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="login-username" name="login-username" placeholder="Username">
</form>
```

How can i read the value of this control in an MVC control, however we cannot use dashes in variable names.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that you use an **underscore** like `login_username`, so that you can take advantage of model binding while passing data from the view to the controller.

Meanwhile you cannot declare the below code as a class attribute

> public string login-username { get; set; }

***NOTE***

if you must use the dash, then consider using `IFormCollection` in ASP.NET core or `FormCollection` in ASP.NET

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(IFormCollection collection)
{
    var login_username = collection["login-username"];
    //Other logic here
    return View();
}
```

Also you can still make use of the model binding but with extra lines of code and some other stuff see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316301/asp-net-mvc-2-bind-a-models-property-to-a-different-named-value#answer-4316327)