# Binding a value of 1 as true for a boolean for WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a PHP program POSTING to a C# MVC WebApi.  The WebApi program starts as:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EmailExists(UsersEmailExistsBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    /* remaining functionality */
}
```

The binding model as as follows:

```
public class UsersEmailExistsBindingModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool Update { get; set; }
}
```

The Update property represents if this is for an existing user or not. i.e Are we doing an update?

When PHP posts the request, it uses Update=1 in the form content, which returns `The value '1' is not valid for Update`.

How can I specify that 1 and 0 should be accepted as valid values for true and false for the boolean value when binding?

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. Add a property with short, and then your bool property wrapping the short property.
2. Implement a `CustomValueProvider` see: [How to map a 1 or 0 in an ASP.Net MVC route segment into a Boolean action method input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027734/how-to-map-a-1-or-0-in-an-asp-net-mvc-route-segment-into-a-boolean-action-method)

Comment: Solution 2 might be better for handling any location that I want to bind 1 and 0 for boolean values. However, ASP.Net MVC is not ASP.Net WebApi, and I'm not sure that their binding techniques are the same.